# Missing lines in table in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

I am trying to create a simple table in beamer. My code is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usetheme{Air}
\usepackage{thumbpdf}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{ucs}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps,pgfshade}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\definecolor{Darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.4,0}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\latintext#1\greektext}
\newcommand{\gr}[1]{\selectlanguage{greek}#1\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\title{\eng{Analyze this}}
\subtitle{\eng{Pitfalls, Analysis, Results}}
\author{Αθανάσιος Σταματόπουλος}
%\date{September 6th 2006}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\eng{Benchmarking Results for $^{nat}B$@$170^\circ$}}
  \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline\\
      \multirow{2}{*}{\eng{Energy}} & \eng{Chiari 10} & \eng{Chiari 10} & \eng{Chiari 10} & \eng{Chiari 10}\\
      & \eng{Chiari 11} & \eng{Mayer($165^\circ$) 11} & \eng{Chiari($165^\circ$) 11} & \eng{Rihet 11}\\
      \hline\\
      $1500$ & $-17.13$ & $-$ & $-$ & $-$\\
      \hline\\
      $2250$ & $-16.98$ & $-4.74$ & $-18.70$ & $-$\\
      \hline\\
      $2800$ & $+2.15$ & $-$ & $-$ & $-$\\
      \hline\\
      $3300$ & $-17.17$ & $-$ & $-$ & $-18.65$\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My output is the following

[image]

Why aren't all the lines filled? what can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the linebreaks after `\hline`

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
      $2800$ & $+2.15$ & $-$ & $-$ & $-$\\
      \hline
      $3300$ & $-17.17$ & $-$ & $-$ & $-18.65$\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Such a stupidity! Thank you very much for your answer!!!